# Calculate or setup overlap calculation in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm having difficulty getting off the ground on a SQL query that I'm trying to write in MS Access 2010.

What my data looks like (simplified)

`Name - - State - - Code
Bob - - NY - - A
Bob - - NY - - B
Bob - - NY - - C
Jane - - FL - - A
Jill - - FL - - B
Bill - - GA - - C
Will - - TN - - A
Will - - TN - - C`

What I'm looking to calculate...
The count of how many unique individuals based on Name and State are in:
`Code A and B (1 in this example)
Code B and C (1 in this example)
Code A and C (2 in this example)`

I'm a SQL novice and I'm at a loss for where to start. A shove in the right direction on how to solve a problem like this would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a self join and aggregation:

```
select t1.code as code1, t2.code as code2, count(*) as NumOverlaps
from table1 as t1 inner join
     table1 as t2
     on t1.name = t2.name and t1.state = t2.state and t1.code < t2.code
group by t1.code, t2.code;
```

Note:  this assumes that there are no duplicates in the original data (your sample data has no duplicates).

Comment: I'll try this out and report back!  One question, on line 4 you wrote: `t1.code < t2.code` why that and not this: `t1.code<>t2.code`

Comment: @ChrisG . . . That is so you only get one of A and B.  If you have A and B together, there is not reason to also include B and A.

Comment: Dang, beat me to it!  I was just about to answer my own question.  Maybe one day I'll be able to keep up with you gurus. :)

Comment: I've adapted the code to my database, double checking against another method and then I'll mark as answered.

Comment: Okay, it took a super long time to validate this, but one of the results is off by 1.  80 thousand plus records in my "table1" and one of the rows of this Query is off by 1 darn count.  Thoughts on how I can trace the error or what might have caused it?

Comment: The query might run faster with an index on `name, state, code`.  However, I don't know how or why one row would have incorrect information.  Possibly the codes have hidden characters or something like that.

Comment: And when I say off by 1, I mean the result for one of the "code" combinations was lower than the validation by 1.  I think I trust the validation method, a little uncertain about the SQL, simply because I'm a newbie.  Throwing ideas out there: could it have something to do with the sort order in table1?

Comment: @ChrisG . . . No.  I would trust the SQL (not surprising since I know nothing about the validation code).  But you should investigate the specific row and determine which one is correct.

Comment: For one row to be off by 1 is driving me nuts. It's so small that it makes it even harder to find.  I'm considering just going forward with the code as is and calling it an acceptable margin of error, I'm just worried that it hides an error that could cause problems.

Comment: I don't think I've said thank you yet.  Seriously, you've been a huge help and your code and the whole process to implement and validate it has taught me tons.

Comment: Still no luck, validated in Excel using several methods:

Comment: Primary method used: Export the raw data from table 1, create a concatenated ID field in Excel based on name and state, make a pivot table using the ID field as rows, the code field as columns, count of id field as values.  Sum the two columns that contain the code value combination that's failing.